# build a custom SplashScreen in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, splash-screen

i've to build a custom SplashScreen for my app. it's nothing special just some image and a rotating loading icon.
the problem is that this splash screen should be displayed for 850 millisecond and then navigate to the main menu but i can't figure out how to do this....
i've tried

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(850);
```

and this solution:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopwatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        while (true)
        {
            //some other processing to do possible
            if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 850)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainMenu.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

but nothing seems to work and the app goes immediatly to MainMenu

how can i do?

Comment: Is it actually going to load anything? You should wait to navigate until it is finished loading

Comment: no it actually don't load anything the whiole splash page it's actually an advertisment for my company wich develop apps for ather companies

Comment: Ah thanks for the info. You may just want to use a Storyboard that starts when the page is loaded, and when it's complete navigate to the next page

Answer (score 0):

on another forum they suggest me this solution:

```
using System.Windows.Threading;
DispatcherTimer Timer = new DispatcherTimer()
{
    Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(850)
};
Timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
    Timer.Stop();
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainMenu.xaml", UriKind.Relative));        
};
Timer.Start();
```

it works!